# How to copy a document with a different ID in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a database (Firebase), and I need to basically copy the data from a table to another corresponding table.
They are all in the same bucket and collection, but different documents (to copy- has data and copy to, which is empty).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific operation to copy a document.

You'll have to:

1. Read the document from its original location
2. Grab the data from the document
3. Write the data to its new/additional location